# Generate a sequence of 2D coordinates which trace a curve. eg. a circle

Tags: c#, 2d, computational-geometry, geo, geometry-surface

While working on a simple Radar simulator, I wish to be able to stream (x,y) coordinates of objects position. Generating object positions moving in random directions does not generate palatable results as it does not look like a path any normal object would take. 
I think having points which trace curves (parabolas, circles, sine curves etc.) with random constants can generate realistic results. 
How does one achieve a sequence of points which in order trace a given curve. 
I am using c#, but no need for the answer to be limited in that sense.

Comment: [This article](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/smooth-random-motions-with-differentiable-random-providers/) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Yes, this seems helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible method is to use a sequence of quadratic or Bezier arcs, preferably choosing the control points to ensure G1 continuity (same tangent at the connection points).

Depending on your need, you can sample a few points along every arc, or join them by Bresenham line segments to trave every pixel.

https://github.com/MtnViewJohn/context-free/wiki/Path-Declarations#bezier-control-points